# magento unable to reroute to controller in config.xml

Tags: magento-1.4

(FYI this is version 1.4, and yes I'm flushing my var/cache folder.  I've started reading through Alan Storm's tutorials and that helped, but nothing specific on this problem)

I am new to Magento, we are using the OnePage checkout method, and we have the following:

`app/code/local/Ourcompany/Checkout/etc/config.xml`

Which has the following definition:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Ourcompany_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Ourcompany_Checkout</Ourcompany_Checkout>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

I have a corresponding file in:

`/app/code/local/Ourcompany/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

In there I have a class:

`class Ourcompany_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`

So far I have not been able to get Magento to acknowledge it's there. The native methods in `core` are being called only.  If I remove or rename this page, there is no error statement - I think my syntax in config.xml is not correct.  Can anyone identify the improper syntax present?

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I have answered my own question but I think the answer here is noteworthy.  The CommerceBug debugger was very useful as I was able to look at classes that were loaded.  As it turns out, there was another module that had been created, called `Admaster` which got precedence as the router for the OnepageController.

I'm sure dealing with this type of conflict is common for Magento, so I have a mental checklist item now if this happens again.